# Proving two integral inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, integration, absolute-value

Can anyone help me to prove that these integral inequalities hold?

Here $x$ is a real value:

$$
\left| \int_a^b\ f(x) dx \right| \leq \int_a^b\ |f(x)| dx
$$

Here $z$ is a complex value:

$$
\left| \int_C^ \ f(z) dz \right| \leq \int_C^\ |f(z)| |dz|
$$

Comment: What is $|dz|$?

Comment: @Did For a contour integral around a path $\gamma(t)$, $|dz|$ is a shorthand for $|\gamma'(t)| dt$

Comment: @user71815 Thanks, I know. My goal with this comment was to help the OP to precise the setting of their question (but, as you can see, the OP was not interested in that).

Answer (score 3):

Notice by the triangle inequality

$$ \Big|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)\Big|\Delta x_i\ \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |f(\xi_i)|\Delta x_i $$ Now when applying limits as $\Delta x_i$ go to $0$, then we obtain the first part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote
$$
f_+(x) = \max\{0, f(x)\}\\
f_-(x) = \max\{0, -f(x)\}
$$
We have
$$
f(x) = f_+(x) - f_-(x)\\
\lvert f(x) \rvert = f_+(x) + f_-(x)\\
\int_a^b f_{\pm} (x) dx \geq 0
$$
and so
$$
\left\lvert \int_a^b f(x)dx \right\rvert = \left\lvert \int_a^b f_+(x)dx - \int_a^b f_-(x)dx\right\rvert \leq\\
\left\lvert \int_a^b f_+(x)dx \right\rvert + \left\lvert\int_a^b f_-(x)dx\right\rvert =\\
\int_a^b f_+(x)dx + \int_a^b f_-(x)dx = \\
 \int_a^b (f_+(x) + f_-(x))dx = \int_a^b\lvert f(x)\rvert dx\\  
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the 2nd integration inequality:

Set $\overline{w}:=\int f(z) dz$ and have a look at $\int \overline{w} f(z) dz$. What happens to the lhs? Write the rhs as a double integral.

Hope this helps.

---

Complete proof of the 2nd inequality:

We know
$\displaystyle \int f(z) dz = \int \text{Re } f(x) dx + i \int \text{Im } f(x) dx$

Set $\overline{w}:=\int f(z) dz$. Then we get $|w|=|\overline{w}|=\left| \int f(x) dx \right|$ and further more

$$\overline{w} \int f(x) dx= \left( \int Re f(x) dx + i \int Im f(x) dx \right)\left( \int Re f(x) dx + i \int Im f(x) dx \right)=\left| \int f(x) \right|^2$$ and so $\displaystyle \overline{w} \int f(x) dx \in \mathbb{R}^+$. We finally have

$$\left| \int f(x) \right|^2 =
 \overline{w} \int f(x) dx =
 Re \left( \int \overline{w} f(x) dx \right) =
 \int Re(\overline{w}f(x))dx \leq\\
\int |\overline{w}f(x)|dx=
\int |\overline{w}||f(x)|dx=
|\overline{w}| \int |f(x)| dx
=\left| \int f(x) dx \right| \int |f(x)| dx \iff\\ \left| \int f(x) dx \right|  \leq
 \int |f(x)| dx$$

I hope I didn't mixed up some absolute values.

Comment: You should spell out that '$|dz|$' stuff..

Answer (score 0):

1. Proving the first inequality

Suppose, WLOG, that

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \neq 0$$

Define

$$ \lambda = \frac{\left| \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \right|}{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx} $$

---

Remark 1: $\lambda \in \{\pm 1,\pm i\}$.

Remark 2: Integrals are homogeneous, i.e.,

$$\forall a\in \mathbb{C} :\int_{a}^{b}a f(x)dx = a \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Remark 3: $\forall a\in \mathbb{C}: |Re(a)|\leq |a|$

---

So, we have

$$\mathbb{R^+} \ni \left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right| = \lambda \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} \lambda f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}Re\{\lambda f(x)\}dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}|Re\{\lambda f(x)\}|dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}|\lambda f(x)|dx \leq |\lambda|\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|dx$$

Finally,

$$ \left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{b}\left|f(x)\right| dx $$

2. Proving the second inequality:

$$\left| \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz \right| = \left| \int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t)) \gamma ' (t) dt \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} \left| f(\gamma(t)) \gamma ' (t)\right| dt =  \int_{a}^{b} \left| f(\gamma(t))\right| \left| \gamma ' (t)\right| dt = \int_{\gamma}\left|f(z)\right||dz|$$