# Inequality in Integrals

Tags: functional-analysis

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ Why $|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx|\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx$?

pdta:$|\cdot|$ is module of complex numbers

Comment: A related question: [Proving two integral inequalities](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216213/proving-two-integral-inequalities)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\left| \int_a^b f(x)dx \right| = e^{-i\theta}\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b e^{-i\theta}f(x)dx$$
where $\theta = \operatorname{Arg}\int_a^b f(x)dx$. But $\left| \int_a^b f(x)dx \right|$ is real, so
$$\left| \int_a^b f(x)dx \right| = \operatorname{Re}\int_a^b e^{-i\theta}f(x)dx = \int_a^b \operatorname{Re}(e^{-i\theta}f(x))dx \leq \int_a^b \left| e^{-i\theta}f(x) \right|dx = \int_a^b \left| f(x) \right|dx.$$

Comment: Why $\int_a^b {\left| {{e^{ - i\theta }}f(x)} \right|dx}  = \int_a^b {\left| {f(x)} \right|dx}$?

Comment: What does Euler formula tell us about $\left| {{e^{ - i\theta }}} \right|$?

Comment: mmm I think that $|f(x)|e^{i\theta} = f(x)$

Comment: I am not sure why you have $\left| {f(x)} \right|{e^{i\theta}}$. Euler formula gives: $\left| {{e^{ - i\theta }}} \right| = \sqrt {{{\cos }^2}(\theta ) + {{\sin }^2}(\theta )}  =  \ldots $ so $\left| {{e^{ - i\theta }}f(x)} \right| = \left| {{e^{ - i\theta }}} \right|\left| {f(x)} \right| =  \ldots $

Comment: mmmm and $|e^{-i\theta}|$ is one?, Why?

Comment: and another question Why $\operatorname{Re} \int_a^b {{e^{ - i\theta }}f(x)dx = } \int_a^b {\operatorname{Re} ({e^{ - i\theta }}f(x))dx}$

Comment: OK, here is the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html) of the mod function and you MUST know that ${\cos ^2}(\theta ) + {\sin ^2}(\theta ) = 1$ and that $\sqrt 1  = 1$. See [Argand diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html) if you are not convinced.

Comment: Regarding Re, note that $\int_a^b {{e^{ - i\theta }}f(x)dx}$ is a number. So it make not difference if you evaluate the integral and take the real part of if you take the real part and evaluate.

Comment: $\int_a^b {{e^{ - i\theta }}f(x)dx}$ is a number? real?

Comment: It is a number, it could be complex or it could be real. It depends on $f(x)$.

Comment: but I don't understand yet Why "... not difference if you evaluate the integral and take the real part of if you take the real part and evaluate.", This is a property between integral and RE function?

Comment: This is exactly the same as $\operatorname{Re} ( - i) =  - \operatorname{Re} i$, for example. If you are not convinced, find a proof in a complex analysis book.

Comment: @glebovg thanks for the answer does this inequality has a name to remember and to quote back when using it thanks

Comment: I do not think this inequality has a name. Sorry.